# iDRAC 6 Express unable to authenticate

Tags: authentication, dell, dell-poweredge, drac

I recently tried to use a Dell iDRAC 6 Express for the first time on a PowerEdge T310. I logged in using the default username and password and clicked around a few of the screens. Suddely the login prompt came back and now it will not accept the default login credentials. I'm pretty sure I didn't change any settings, so I'm not sure why it will not let me log in.

Any suggestions? In case I did change the password unwittingly somehow (though I'm pretty sure I didn't), would there be a way to reset it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to reset the iDRAC Express from within the Setup (BIOS).

Just an FYI for others: I learned (rather painfully) that the iDRAC Express *does not* have remote console functionality, you can only manage power (reboot, power on/off, etc.) as well as monitor fans, temperatures, and a few other features.

Comment: +1 Good point about the Express card not having remote console access.

Comment: I chewed out my Dell rep for failing to mention that to me when I asked, "does this server come with DRAC?".  It's a sad day when the "RAC" in DRAC is not there.

Comment: It does seem like a rather limited device when all you can do is turn off the power without being able to see what's on the screen.

Comment: IPMI should still allow remote console (serial console redirection).

Comment: @AndreasM: which is pretty useless on Windows.